# Pass ui Structure to insertUI?

Tags: r, shiny

I need a conditionalPanel to only display when a variable reads "15". The observeEvent in which that variable is processed updates its value several times, once to "4", then to "15" at the end; I need the conditionalPanel to be hidden while the value of the variable is "4" in the observeEvent, then be displayed at the end, when the value is "15".

GitHub CoPilot tells me the best way to try this is to move the conditionalPanel to the server section, encase it in an if(variable == 15) statement, then output the if statement with a renderUI to an output$ variable.

This works, except that in the conditionalPanel in question, there is a uiOutput statement of a checkboxGroupInput that is not rendering with the conditionalPanel in the server section.

GitHub CoPilot again tells me the best way to output the checkboxGroupInput is to use an insertUI statement. I am using

```
insertUI(selector="#chooseVars",
  where="afterEnd",
  ui=checkboxGroupInput(inputId =  "varCheckboxes",
    label =  "Variables",
    choices = JeffDF$colVars # ,
    # selected = JeffDF$defaultVars
    )
)
```

However, this returns the error, "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'". I suspect this means I'm doing the "ui =" statement in the insertUI statement wildly wrong, but I don't have any experience with insertUI statements. Could someone suggest a "ui =" statement that will work with my situation?

EDIT: Here should be a minimal, runnable, reproducible example; sorry for the wait.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("menuInputs"),
  actionButton(inputId = "go",
               label = "Go")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$varCheckboxes <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId =  "varCheckboxes",
                       label =  "Variables",
                       choices = c("Var1", "Var2"),
                       selected = c("Var1"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$go,
               
               {showProgress <- shiny::Progress$new(session, min = 0, max = 16)
           showProgress$set(value = 4, detail = "Wait")
                 
                 testit <- function(x)
                 {
                   p1 <- proc.time()
                   Sys.sleep(x)
                   proc.time() - p1 # The cpu usage should be negligible
                 }
                 testit(3.7)
                 
                 output$menuInputs <- renderUI({
                   if(showProgress$getValue() == 15){
                     conditionalPanel(condition = "true",
                                      radioButtons('chooseVars', "Select variables as group", choiceNames = c("All Items", "Common Items", "Deselect All"), choiceValues = c("All Items", "Common Items", "Deselect All"), selected = "Common Items"),
                                      # uiOutput('varCheckboxes')
                                      insertUI(selector="#chooseVars",
                                               where="afterEnd",
                                               ui=checkboxGroupInput(inputId =  "varCheckboxes",
                                                                     label =  "Variables",
                                                                     choices = c("Var1"),
                                                                     selected = c("Var1", "Var2")
                                               )
                                      )
                     )
                   }
                 })  
                 
                 showProgress$set(value = 15, detail = "Go")
                 
               })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, runnable, reproducible example](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/wiki/Creating-a-Reproducible-Example) for your shiny app. It's not very clear exactly what you are doing or what values are stored in these variable currently. It's easier to help if we can run and test code to verify that it works or at least reproduce the same error.

Comment: Done. Let me know what you think.

Comment: When I run the code you provided the page opens without error for me. When I press "go" i get an error about that says `Error in observe: object 'showProgress' not found`. It does not replicate the `cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'` error message you get. Tested with `shiny_1.8.0`

Comment: Updated and verified as 1) functioning and 2) reproducing error. Sorry for not testing it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put `insertUI` inside `conditionalPanel`, that makes no sense.

I don't understand what you want to do. Below is a proposal, please leave some comments.

You can use a reactive value `Value`, and in an output slot `value`, a reactive conductor returning `Value()`:

```r
  Value <- reactiveVal(0)  
  output$value <- reactive({
    Value()
  })
  outputOptions(output, "value", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

Thanks to `outputOptions(output, "value", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`, you can use the condition `output.value == 15` for the conditional panel.

Now run the progress bar and set `Value` to `15` at the end.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Click me"),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.value === 15",
    radioButtons(
      'chooseVars', "Select variables as group", 
      choiceNames = c("All Items", "Common Items", "Deselect All"), 
      choiceValues = c("All Items", "Common Items", "Deselect All"), 
      selected = "Common Items"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Value <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  output$value <- reactive({
    Value()
  })
  outputOptions(output, "value", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    progress <- Progress$new(session, min = 1, max = 16)
    on.exit(progress$close())
    progress$set(value = 4, detail = "wait")
    Sys.sleep(5)
    progress$set(value = 15, detail = "ok")
    Value(15)
  })
  
  observe({
    req(Value() == 15)
    insertUI(
      "#chooseVars",
      "afterEnd",
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId =  "varCheckboxes",
                         label =  "Variables",
                         choices = c("Var1", "Var2"),
                         selected = "Var1")
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But I don't see the interest of this conditional panel. Instead one could use a `uiOutput` containing the radio buttons and the checkboxes:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Click me"),
  uiOutput("panel")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Value <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    progress <- Progress$new(session, min = 1, max = 16)
    on.exit(progress$close())
    progress$set(value = 4, detail = "wait")
    Sys.sleep(5)
    progress$set(value = 15, detail = "ok")
    Value(15)
  })
  
  output$panel <- renderUI({
    req(Value() == 15)
    tagList(
      radioButtons(
        'chooseVars', "Select variables as group", 
        choiceNames = c("All Items", "Common Items", "Deselect All"), 
        choiceValues = c("All Items", "Common Items", "Deselect All"), 
        selected = "Common Items"
      ),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId =  "varCheckboxes",
                         label =  "Variables",
                         choices = c("Var1", "Var2"),
                         selected = "Var1")
    )
  })
  
}
```

---

## EDIT

Maybe this is closer to what you want:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ipc)
library(future)
plan(multisession)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("go", "Click me"),
  br(),
  tags$label("Value is:"),
  textOutput("displayValue"),
  br(),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.value === 15",
    radioButtons(
      'chooseVars', "Select variables as group", 
      choiceNames = c("All Items", "Common Items", "Deselect All"), 
      choiceValues = c("All Items", "Common Items", "Deselect All"), 
      selected = "Common Items"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Value <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  output$value <- reactive({
    Value()
  })
  outputOptions(output, "value", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  output$displayValue <- renderText({
    Value()
  })

  queue <- shinyQueue()
  queue$consumer$start(100) # Execute signals every 100 milliseconds
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    progress <- AsyncProgress$new(session, min = 1, max = 16)
    future({
      progress$set(value = 4, detail = "wait")
      queue$producer$fireAssignReactive("Value", 4)
      Sys.sleep(5)
      progress$set(value = 15, detail = "ok")
      queue$producer$fireAssignReactive("Value", 15)
      progress$close()
    })
    NULL    
  })
  
  observe({
    req(Value() == 15)
    insertUI(
      "#chooseVars",
      "afterEnd",
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId =  "varCheckboxes",
                         label =  "Variables",
                         choices = c("Var1", "Var2"),
                         selected = "Var1")
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering! Unfortunately, the Value() (which, what I kind-of need is Value(4) after the progress$set(value = 4 [...]) to hide the conditionalPanel when the progress is not 15, BID) does not appear to update mid-observeEvent as I need. If anyone has any other suggestions, they would be most welcome.

Comment: @JeffreyRolland Sorry I don't understand the behavior you expect. Do you have a less artifical example?

Comment: I've actually had something come up at work, so it might be after the weekend until I get back to you, but I have another example almost made up, and shall post it as soon as I am able to do so.

Comment: The fireAssignReactive-thing solved the problem! I'll post a working solution in a minute; thanks so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so, Stéphane Laurent's solution actually solved the problem. Just for completeness, here is my solution to the problem using my "paradigm" for the shiny page to be designed and M. Laurent's solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(ipc)
library(future)
plan(multisession)

ui <- fluidPage(
  conditionalPanel(condition = "output.someCondition == 'TRUE'",
                   actionButton(inputId = "go", # Some stuff that should display when output$someCondtition is true
                                label = "Go"),
                   textOutput("value"),
                   # Some other stuff that should display when output$someCondtition is true
                   conditionalPanel(condition = "output.value == 15", # This part should be hidden unless output$someCondtition is true and progress = 15
                                    radioButtons(inputId = "chooseVars",
                                                 label = "Select variables", 
                                                 choices = c("Var1", "Var2"), 
                                                 selected = c("Var1")
                                    )
                   )
                   # Some more stuff that should display when output$someCondtition is true
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Value01 <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  
  output$someCondition <- renderText({Value01()})
  outputOptions(output, "someCondition", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  Value02 <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  output$value <- reactive({Value02()})
  outputOptions(output, "value", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  output$displayValue <- renderText({Value02()})
  
  queue <- shinyQueue()
  queue$consumer$start(100) # Execute signals every 100 milliseconds
  
  observeEvent(input$go,
               
               {
                 showProgress <- AsyncProgress$new(session, min = 1, max = 16)
                 
                 future({
                   showProgress$set(value = 4, detail = "Wait")
                   queue$producer$fireAssignReactive("Value02", 4)
                   
                   Sys.sleep(5) #Actually doing stuff; this is just a proxy/placeholder. We only want the inner conditionalPanel displayed when this is done running
                   
                   showProgress$set(value = 15, detail = "Go")
                   queue$producer$fireAssignReactive("Value02", 15)
                   
                   showProgress$close()
                 })
                 NULL
               })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```